# Android GoogleMap draw line through a known way

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, google-polyline

I am using Google Map Api V2 and I can marker or draw a line between two points.But I try to draw a line through the route of a bus.So Route,Ways,Stopping places...etc of the bus are already known.First of all, I tried to find all LatLong values of the route and I draw it as polylines but I guess it is wasting time.So I want to draw line without find out all LatLong points of route of the bus.Is there any way ?

Thanks for the help..

Comment: Unfortunately, page not found

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/...

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-directions-for-driving-mode-bicycling-and-walking-mode-in-google-map-android-api-v2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to get the directions between two points, but this probably wont match your bus routes.